# Bilinear form on Hilbert Space is Lower Semicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification

I'm working on the following problem -- I just wanted to check the proof:

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $a(u,v)$ be a nonnegative bilinear form on $H$. Prove $a(u,v)$ is lower semicontinuous with respect to weak convergence. I.e.
>   $$u_{\epsilon} \rightharpoonup u \implies a(u,u) \leq \liminf_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} a(u_{\epsilon},u_{\epsilon})$$

My attempt:
We want to show the set $\{u\in H |a(u,u)\leq \lambda\}$ is weakly closed.

First observe:
$$a(u,u) = \langle Au,u \rangle \quad \text{ Reisz Rep}\\=\lim_{\delta_1}\langle Au,u_{\delta_1}\rangle \quad \text{weak cvg} \\ = \lim_{\delta_2}\lim_{\delta_1}\langle Au_{\delta_2},u_{\delta_1}\rangle \quad \text{weak cvg}$$
The way its written, we take a limit along $\delta_2$ then along $\delta_1$. Because the limit is unique, this will remain true if we repeat the second limit procedure for any $n > \delta_1$. Thus one may imagine a sequence of $\delta_2$ for each $n > \delta_1$. Consider the set $$\{\langle Au_{\delta_2},u_{\delta_1}\rangle | \delta_1 = \delta_2 \}$$ which is the subsequence formed by choosing one element from each sequences described above. The limit will be $a(u,u)$ because the limit is unique. Thus we have:

$$a(u,u) = \langle Au,u \rangle \quad \text{ Reisz Rep}\\=\lim_{\delta_1=\delta_2=\epsilon}\langle Au_{\epsilon},u_{\epsilon}\rangle \quad \text{by shinangans above}  \\ \leq |\langle Au_{\epsilon},u_{\epsilon} \rangle| \\ \leq \sup_{\epsilon} |\langle Au_{\epsilon},u_{\epsilon} \rangle| \leq \lambda$$

Thus $\{u\in H |a(u,u)\leq \lambda\}$ is weakly closed, so $a(u,u)$ is lsc. $\blacksquare$

Mainly I wasn't sure because of what I did in the first part of the proof with obtaining the correct sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*} (Au_\epsilon,u_\epsilon) &= (A u_\epsilon,u) + (Au_\epsilon,u_\epsilon-u) \\
&= (A u_\epsilon,u) + (A(u_\epsilon-u),u_\epsilon-u) +(Au,u_\epsilon-u).\end{align*}

The first summand is equal to $(u_\epsilon,A^*u)$ and therefore converges to $(u,A^*u)=(Au,u)$. The third converges to zero. 
The middle is nonnegative by the *nonnegativity* assumption, and therefore its $\liminf \ge 0$.

Comment: Okay, from your arguement I see that $a(u_{\epsilon},u_{\epsilon}) \geq a(u,u)$. But why does that imply the $\liminf a(u_{\epsilon},u_{\epsilon}) \geq a(u,u)$ though? Can't the LHS "oscillate" and give a $\liminf$ lower than $a(u,u)$?

Comment: LHS=RHS. RHS has first and third elements converging to $(Au,u)$ and to $0$, respectively. Second element is always nonnegative so its $\liminf$ is nonnegative.